# find 1)$(span\{u,v\})^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the standard inner product.  vectors $u =(1,0)$ and $v =(1,-1)$

find

1)$(span\{u,v\})^{\perp}$

2)$span\{u^{\perp}, v^{\perp}\}$

## My attempts :

i know that $u^\perp$ is the y axis and $v^\perp$ is the line $y =x $

Now i can said that $span\{u^{\perp}, v^{\perp}\}=  span \{y,x\}= \mathbb{R}^2$

Now  im here  confusing about  that how to find  $(span\{u,v\})^{\perp}$?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: You are right. And what's span(u,v)?

Comment: @ amsmath  ...span{(1,0)  , (-1,1)}= [-1,1]...i may  be  wrong  its  just my thinking

Comment: What does $[-1,1]$ mean? If you mean the interval, that's horribly false.

Comment: @amsmath..ya i was wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*  $span\{u,v\}=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: then what is $({\mathbb{R}^2})^{\perp}$  ? can u elaborate more..

Comment: $(\mathbb R^2)^{\perp}$ is...  the only element whose inner product with everything is zero...